# The best way to fetch server data to your React + Redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Hi guys this is a general question about how to implement my application using React and Redux.

## My Application

I am building a web app in react for managing competitions (more details here https://ziggy6792.github.io/posts/wakeboard-competition-app/)

I have a graphql backend (amplify Appsync api) with several data objects (nested as follows);

- Events

  - Competitions

    - Heats

I will store the fetched data in redux.

I will have a /event route to display event data and then allow a user to navigate to child competitions and child heats. I want users to be able to share links to competitions/events/heats so will include ids in window.location.search params.

E.g:
myApp/events?id=eventId

Event Name: My Event

Competitions

- Competition1 (link to comp1)
- Competition2 (link to comp2)

## My Plan

I have implemented a graphql endpont (getDataEntity(String! Id)) that can receive an id and return the Event/Competition/Heat for that id. I thought this would be a good approach as I can share a lot of the dispatching actions and updating state logic without needing to specify which exact data entities I am loading (also object ids are globally unique so I don't see any issue in this approach).

Then I can use the window.location.search params to set and load ids of the entities I want to display in on the page.
E.g. myapp.com/events?dataEntityId=123

In theory as a user clicks around the application any of this data can change at any time (i.e; if judges add new results for a competition).

### A simple solution?

So as far as I can tell the simplest working solution would be to always fetch all the data for each data entity when a page is loaded (showing a spinner until I receive the data) and then store it in my redux store. E.g.

```
events:{
   laodedDataEntiy: {id, "123", type: "Event", name: "My Event", description: "Wellcome..."},
}
```

However I think this is a bit of a stupid implementation because most of the time when a page is loaded the data will not have changed so making the user wait for refetching is a waste of time.

### A better solution?

I was thinking a better solution might be to to store the loaded data entities by id in my redux store e.g.

```
events:{
   laodedDataEntities:{
     "123": {id, "123", type: "Event", name: "My Event", description: "Wellcome..."},
     "456": {id, "456", type: "Competition", name: "My Competition", description: "Wellcome..."},
    }
}
```

Then when loading a page I can immediately display whatever (if anything) is in the redux sore for the dataEntityId from my url. Then asynchronously call my endpoint to get the (potentially) updated data and update my redux store. I can use React.memo to only re-render if the data  in redux is different to my current props (as in the data that was first loaded).

I would essentially be using my redux store as a cache for what's on the server so my pages can load quickly before checking for any changes.

### Questions

1. What do you think of my proposed solution?
2. Am I overcomplicating this?
3. What is the standard approach here (any examples would be great!)?
4. Any pitfalls I should be aware of?

I guess that this is either a pretty common way to implement this or it's not because of some important reasons I haven't thought of.

Thanks a lot,

Simon

Comment: Why don’t you use Apollo instead? It takes care of everything for you out of the box

Answer (score 0):

**Standard** (most widely used) **is "Apollo client"** (with normalizing cache, error handling etc.), it probably covers all your data manipulations needs, even real time updates (subscriptions).

You can use other "graphQL client" (f.e. Relay).

Of course **you can use `fetch` or `axios` but it is an option mainly for simple use cases**, f.e. single queries or data without complex relations.

**You can still use redux for main goals it was designed for - global app state** - f.e. saving state of hideable modals, remember sorting preference ... but almost all of this (local state) can be done in Apollo, too. F.e. `login` mutation, logged user data, friends...

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the reply. If I use Apollo client can I keep my backend api? Is Apollo client just something I add in the front end React app to replace the aws-amplify package.

At the moment I call my API like this;

import Amplify, { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
const response = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listEvents));

Are you saying that I can replace 'aws-amplify' with Apollo client and get these local caching features that I want.
Any good tutorials on how to set up "Apollo client" with an aws Apppsync backend.
What about setting up subscriptions too?

Comment: I found this found this which shows how to setup Apollo Client with Appsync. https://dev.to/johndemian/react-graphql-app-with-aws-amplify-and-appsync-are-amazing-60g
 Looks like exactly what I was looking for and glad I don't have to implement the cache from scratch. Thanks a lot for pointing me in this direction!